# bootstrap show/hide input depended on radio

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to have two radio buttons.

The first is called "Use an existing" and the second is called "Create new scene".

There should be hidden input under radios and if I check the "Create new scene" radio, there should appear the input. If i check the first radio "Use an existing", the input should hide again.

My question is: Is there any way to achieve that by bootstrap or I have to use JQuery?

Comment: JQuery. Bootstrap is just CSS, and rather than using CSS you should use an actual scripting language like JQuery for that.

Comment: Of course, Bootstrap utilizes the predefined function in JQuery. Therefore, I ask if there is such function, respectively if there is some way to use it.

Comment: No, essentially you would basically just call some Bootstrap function which in turn would call a JQuery one. You are better off just going straight to JQuery rather than taking an extra step.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, you would have to use JQuery, there is not a built in function of Bootstrap do that.

Bootstrap is built on JQuery, so you essentially are always using JQuery.

Comment: You only have to use Jquery, if you want the javascript features of Bootstrap ;)